# Performance issue when using AndroidView and composable (MapBox)

Tags: android, view, maps, android-jetpack-compose-material3

I am currently adding a Map to a projet with the MapLibre library (fork from mapBox) and every time I change a value in the composable the UI freeze giving an openGlRenderer warning in logcat :
[logcat from openGlRenderer](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AwiJm.png)

I am actually implementing the mapBoxMap in an androidView inside an @Composable screen, I am getting onMapClick the value of the point Clicked on my map, while this value stays in the scope of the map, changing it doesn't cause any issue, but when changing a mutable value outside, not even used in any part of any screen, changing this simple string value cause a 500ms to 2000ms freeze and break the animation.

When I remove this value from the screen and only update it in viewModel no performance issues are seen.

I didn't currently try the R8 build that could fix the performance issue.